# TYPO3 felogin - Creating custom marker with a hook to render content based on language?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x, felogin

I tried to make a language switch in the felogin template like below:

```
<!--###FORGOTP_VALID###-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
        <p class="loginlink"><span><!--###FORGOT_PASSWORD_LINK###-->###FORGOT_PASSWORD###<!--###FORGOT_PASSWORD_LINK###--></span></p>
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <f:if condition="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.language')} == 'en'">    
            <p><span>Don't have an account? <a href="/sign-up/">Sign up for free!</a></span></p>
        </f:if> 
        <f:if condition="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.language')} == 'de'">        
            <p><span>Noch kein Account? <a href="de/sign-up/">Kostenlos registrieren!</a></span></p>
        </f:if>             
    </div>
</div>
```

But its ignoring the conditions. What am I missing?

EDIT: I added a hook like suggested here https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/felogin/Hooks/Index.html and example here http://labor.99grad.de/2017/07/29/typo3-fe_login-um-eigene-marker-erweitern/ ... but I get a blank page on the login page now.

I added $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['felogin']['postProcContent'] in one of my extensions 'accountmanager'

In ext_tables.php I added:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['felogin']['postProcContent']['gwl_add_marker'] = 'EXT:accountmanager/Classes/Hooks/FeUserHook->addMarker';
```

In my main setup.ts I added:

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1 {
    templateFile = EXT:accountmanager/Resources/Private/Templates/Felogin/FrontendLogin.html
    settings {
        pidMainPage = 354
    }
}
```

and in Ext:accountmanager/Classes/Hooks/FeUserHook.php I have:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Accountmanager\Hooks;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;   

class FeUserHook {

    /**
     *  Fügt alle Settings als Marker für das FrontendLogin.html-Template ein
     *  im Stil von: ###settings.pidMainPage###
     *
     */
    public function addMarker ( $params, $_this ) {

        $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
        $cObj = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer');

        $settings = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['plugin.']['tx_felogin_pi1.']['settings.'];
        $marker = [];
        foreach ($settings as $k=>$v) {
            $marker["###settings.{$k}###"] = $v;
        }
        $content = $cObj->substituteMarkerArrayCached($params['content'], $marker);
        return $content;
```

But when I place the marker in EXT:accountmanager/Resources/Private/Templates/Felogin/FrontendLogin.html

```
   ###settings.pidMainPage###
```

... I get a blank page ...

Answer (score 0):

The felogin extension does not use Fluid so you cannot use any conditions in your template.

However, you can achieve this with the [Hairu extension](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/hairu/) which does use Fluid.

Notice that in this case you don't actually need conditions since your intention can be resolved with  `<f:translate>`.

Comment: Is there any other way to not install another extension?

Comment: There is a hook `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['felogin']['postProcContent']` which is explicitly advertised as _Adds hook for processing of extra item markers / special_.

Comment: I tried to add a hook ... but getting a white page now.